# fslview in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I installed fsl-complete on Ubuntu 18.04 from NeuroDebian. I could find functions of fsl and they seem to work, but I could not find fslview.
The command of the fsl functions looks like this:

```
$fsl5.0-fslinfo #For example fslinfo
```

But there is no

```
$fsl5.0-fslview
```

Neither:

```
$fslview
```

Does anyone know where to find the fslview or where to install it separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fslview is replaced by fsleyes in the recent FSL release.

More details:
https://fsl.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/fsl/fslwiki/FSLeyes